# How can we ask jmeter to process the next record which has unique number

Tags: jmeter

I need to click and submit a sequential record in my application every time a concurrent user logged in.  should not select a same record because the submit button wont available for the same record if the concurrent user tries to select.  I do have 40 pages which jmeter should automatically select next record every time user logged in. Per page 10 records will be there, and 300 concurrent users will logged in.

Please advise what need to mention in bean-shell?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "click" any buttons, it acts on [HTTP protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) therefore you need to investigate what network request does "button click" cause and what are the differences between them.

Most probably it's a matter of simple [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start),  so you need to do something like:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your test plan
2. Add HTTP Request sampler to the setUp Thread Group and configure it to iterate 40 pages and extract the unique numbers (or other unique button identifiers) using the suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into JMeter Variables. You should end with something like:

   ```
   VAR_1=unique_number_1
   VAR_2=unique_number_2
   ...
   VAR_400=unique_number_400
   ```
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the setUp Thread Group and use the following Groovy code to convert the variables to JMeter Properties

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   vars.entrySet().each { variable ->
       if (variable.getKey().startsWith('VAR_')) {
           props.put(variable.getKey(), variable.getValue())
       }
   }
   ```
4. That's it, in the main Thread Group you can use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination so each thread (virtual user) will get its own "button" to "click" like:

   ```
   ${__P(VAR_${__threadNum},)}
   ```